# how to increment invoice no. whenever I click order?

Tags: php

My table columns are invoiceid (primary AI), invoiceno, purchaseorderno, userid. I figured I couldn't use invoiceid since for example: when a customer buys 2 products, the 2 invoiceid will be diff. So I decided to use invoiceno  that whenever the user will click order and he bought for example 2 products, they will have the same invoiceno. I have this code below:

```
 $invoice = 0000000;
 $invoiceno = $invoice + 1;

$sqlString1 = "INSERT INTO invoice 
               (invoiceno, purchaseorderno, userid) 
               VALUES ('$invoiceno', '$purchaseorderno', '$userid');";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlString1);
```

It works but then the invoice no stay as 1. It doesn't increment when I click order. If my idea is wrong, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do they have to int's or can you use a string.

Comment: if the invoiceno is an `auto_increment` you shouldn't include it in insert statement.

Comment: _"when a customer buys 2 products"_ it should still be the same invoice(no|id). So your logic is wrong somewhere else.

Comment: The logic isn't wrong, the structure of the database is wrong, they need 2 tables, one for invoice one for invoice line items.

Comment: anywhere....the logic is wrong if this problem occurs

Comment: "when a customer buys 2 products, the 2 invoiceid will be diff" not if you normalize your database structure better.

Comment: @Jeff yes, they should have the same invoice. That's why I thought when the costumer orders 2 items and of course if it is auto_increment, they would have diff invoice which is wrong

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in two tables not one.

You have `invoice` and `invoice_item` Which have a One to Many relationship.

If you make another table for the line items, all you problems evaporate.

Table invoice

```
 id
 date
 total
 status etc...
```

Table invoice_item

```
 id
 invoice_id - foreign key
 product_id
 quantity
 etc...
```

Selecting them is no problem

```
 SELECT 
    {fields}
 FROM
    invoice AS i
 JOIN
    invoice_item AS l ON i.id = l.invoice_id
 WHERE
     i.id = :id
```

And so on....

Then you can just use the Primary key from invoices and your all set. It will also be more robust (less prone to breaking) probably faster, probably easier to code in the long run and so on.

It does add a tiny bit of complexity to the data model, and a bit more caution when doing inserts and deletes and what not, but if you setup the foreign key restraints correctly, use transactions when doing inserts, you should be fine.

**UPDATE**

Here is a [DBfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mfE2u7WvJUCAZGt7rQ1F85/1) (click it) with a number of examples of how to setup the forign key and how to build the basic table relationship.  I just guessed at these fields you can of course make any changes you need to, to add or remove them.  This is just for the sake of explaining it.

```
CREATE TABLE invoice(
    id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    total DECIMAL(6,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    submission_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE invoice_item(
    id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    product_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    qty INT(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    sub_total DECIMAL(6,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_InvoiceItems FOREIGN KEY(invoice_id) REFERENCES invoice(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    KEY(product_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Just a few Query examples:

Insert invoice

```
 #in the example fiddle this is AI #2 so invoice.id=2
INSERT INTO invoice (total,email) VALUES ('100.00','user2@example.com');
```

Insert related invoice items

```
#both of these line items have same invoice,
INSERT INTO invoice_item (invoice_id,product_id,qty,sub_total) VALUES ('2','200','7','70.00');
INSERT INTO invoice_item (invoice_id,product_id,qty,sub_total) VALUES ('2','270','2','30.00');
```

Basic Inner Join (selects all invoices that have items, and their items)

```
SELECT
    i.*, l.id AS invoice_item_id, l.product_id, l.qty
FROM
    invoice AS i
LEFT JOIN
    invoice_item AS l ON i.id = l.invoice_id;
```

Count the number of unique Items

```
SELECT
    invoice_id, COUNT(id) AS unique_items
FROM
    invoice_item
GROUP BY invoice_id;
```

Count the number of total items. You can sum, sub_total to get total the same way.  You could remove `invoice.total` if you want to. It can be nice to have the total counted up in there, but you also have to keep it updated when/if you change the number of items in an invoice.

```
SELECT
    invoice_id, SUM(qty) AS total_items
FROM
    invoice_item
GROUP BY invoice_id;
```

Find any invoices without items (its impossible to add items without invoices with the fk constraint, which is exactly what we want)

```
SELECT
    i.*, l.id AS invoice_item_id, l.product_id, l.qty
FROM
    invoice AS i
LEFT JOIN
    invoice_item AS l ON i.id = l.invoice_id
WHERE
    l.id IS NULL;
```

And Last, Delete an invoice, because of the constraint this will cascade and delete the related items from invoice_item with no extra work,in other words the items are auto-magicaly deleted. I've also found letting the database do the cascade delete is significantly faster then manually deleting them.

```
 DELETE FROM invoice WHERE id=2;
```

In this data model, I have the invoice_items grouped by products.  So for invoice.id #2, we have two items, one with product id #200, which is toy ufo's. The other is #270 which is metallic weather balloons.  Tiny Tim got 7 UFO's for $10 each for a sub_total of $70, and then he got 2 weather balloons for $15 each (nothing our government does is cheap).

Ok that is my DB 101 lesson for the day.

**UPDATE1**

Based on this error

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

This is actually a good thing, it's the purpose of the foreign key.  I will try to explain

If you do this insert

```
 INSERT INTO invoice (total,email) VALUES ('100.00','user2@example.com');
```

This creates a row in `invoice`, it's the purpose of insert. Now because it's Auto Increment Id and this is the first row it's `id` is `1`.  Because it's the first row its also the only record in `invoice`. We can all agree on that, I insert 1 row in a new table, that makes it the first and only row.  And it has an AI id of `1`

Now if I try to insert

```
 INSERT INTO invoice_item (invoice_id,product_id,qty,sub_total) VALUES ('2','200','7','70.00');
```

This row has an `invoice_id` of `2`, and we just said we have one invoice with an `id` of `1`.  So there is no invoice with an `id` of `2`.  This will give you the same error you just got, because you are trying to add an `invoice_item` without having it's associated `invoice`, which is something we never want to happen. This is called an "orphan" row because it's parent row does not exist.  If we allowed this our Database could be filled with invoice items that have no invoice.  Then if we later add an invoice with the id of one of those orphan rows we have just associated things that should not be associated. This is why that error makes sense and why it's a good thing.

The obvious way to fix this is to not insert `invoice_items` that don't belong to an `invoice`.

I really hope that makes sense.

So how do we insert `invoice_items` that do have an `invoice`?

In PHP you want to insert the invoice then get it's id, then insert the invoice_item. See this page.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//insert invoice
$query = "INSERT INTO invoice (total,email) VALUES ('100.00','user2@example.com')";
$mysqli->query($query);
//insert invoice item with last insert id
$query = "INSERT INTO invoice_item (invoice_id,product_id,qty,sub_total) VALUES ('".$mysqli->insert_id."','200','7','70.00')";
```

The important part here is to use, `$mysqli->insert_id` when inserting invoice items.  Now if you want to add an invoice item to an existing invoice that was inserted some time ago.  Then you just query the invoice, and pull it's id out and use that for the new invoice item.

Hope that helps, enjoy!

Comment: so invoice_id is not AI? how will i code it in php? I tried the code above but all it output in invoiceno is 1.

Comment: No it is the AI, but it's the foreign key in the `invoice_item` table.  `invoice_item.invoice_id = invoice.id`  that is the field that ties the two tables together.  Do you know what Many To One relationships are, and how they work?  I can explain it a bit and maybe point you to a few resources if you dont.

Comment: so if the user order two items they will have diff. invoice id since it is AI?

Comment: No, they will have the same invoice id, but different  invoice_item.id.  Because the items go in a second table with a Many to One relationship with invoice.

Comment: Sure I suggest doing a bit of research on how to model data in MySql and just get a bit of practice in doing different types of queries.  Data modeling is a balancing act between to much complexity and not enough.  I've been doing it for about 8 years and I am still learning new things all the time.  Just never stop improving your coding abilities and think of the database model in terms of how well does it fit the data.  Does it cover all the things I need it to.

Comment: hi, whenever I insert into invoice_item it says: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: That is probably because you have to have an FK id that matches a row in the other table.  This is actually a good thing, otherwise you would get itmes without an invoice.  In the DBFiddle I linked, on the left side at the bottom is an insert that is commented out with a `#`, this row is an example of exactly the error you have.  If you look at it it has an `invoice_id` of `10` if you look in `invoice` table there is no id `10` so there is no row to associate with it, that is the reason for that error.  If you remove that # before it, you will see it produces the very same error.

Comment: The way to fix that is to make sure your invoice_item has an invoice_id that matches a row in the invoice table.  You either have to know it ahead of time, or if you just inserted the invoice record you can use the last insert ID google it.

Comment: I looked up at w3school about foreign key but still it produces the same error. Here I put it in dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bVyWEdijcxYcxRVeCdE3GZ/0 . Sorry if I kept on asking. :(

Comment: maybe there isn't a problem with the tables at all. the problem is how I should code it in php. Anyway, thank you for your time and patience! Will figure this out.

Comment: AS I said I updated the answer to explain exactly what is happening and why, other then that I don't know what to say.  I would suggest if you have more questions to post them as a separate Question as this one is getting long.